Choice between present perfect and present simple

Danny ____ hard for long to realize his dream and now he is popular.
A. has worked  
B. worked 
C. works 
D. has been working
Key: A

Do you interpret "for long"= "for long hours"？ And what about B.

"for long" on its own is not idiomatic. You would need "for a long time" or maybe "for years".

@DanielRoseman  If it is taken to meam "for a long time", which option is better? And if it were "for long hours", which tense would you use? Thanks.

A bad question. A, B and D would all be possible.

@KateBunting Thank you.  " A, B and D would all be possible. " based on "for a long time"？

Based on either interpretation. All refer to work that was done in the past. (After seeing your last comment) Why should he not still be working hard?

@KateBunting  I want to argue that A is a lesser choice. "... has worked hard for a long time"  seems to suggest he is still working hard, the meaning doesn't quite fit in the sentence.  What do you think?

"For long" can be idiomatic when it is negated. "Danny had not been working for long when..." "Danny will not have this job for long..."

OP's query:

Danny ____ hard for long to realize his dream and now he is popular.
A. has worked
B. worked.
C. works.
D. has been working.

Answer: The correct answer is.
A. "has worked".
In this context, "for long" is understood as "for a long time" or "over an extended period," rather than "for long hours." The phrase "for long" is an idiomatic expression indicating duration.
The present perfect tense "has worked" is the most appropriate here because it shows that the action of working hard began in the past and remains relevant to Danny's current state of being popular.

We use the present perfect:

for something that happened in the past but is important in the present:
I can't get in the house. I've lost my keys.


Edit -1.
A, B, and D would all be possible" While all these tenses could be grammatically correct, the present perfect is contextually the best fit due to the explicit mention of "and now he is popular." In an examination, you got to choose a single correct answer.
"Has worked suggests he is still working hard." This interpretation isn't accurate. Has worked simply connects past actions to the present result. It doesn't inherently mean he continues to work hard. For ongoing action, has been working would be more appropriate, but that isn’t the focus of this sentence

"A, B, and D would all be possible"
While all these tenses could be grammatically correct, the present perfect is contextually the best fit due to the explicit mention of "and now he is popular."
"Has worked suggests he is still working hard."
This interpretation isn't accurate. Has worked simply connects past actions to the present result. It doesn't inherently mean he continues to work hard. For ongoing action, has been working would be more appropriate, but that isn’t the focus of this sentence.

@Barmar Noted. I included it.
